# Sobolev spaces on domains and manifolds, what is the difference?

Tags: manifolds, sobolev-spaces, compact-manifolds

What are the (technical) differences between Sobolev spaces on domains $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ or (compact) manifolds such as two-dimensional spheres?